# Changing css based on value comparison in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a group of divs with unique attrs

```
<div ng-repeat="data in data">
    <p data-id="home_{{$index}}">{{data}}</p>
</div>
```

The data looks like this,

```
$scope.data = {"a":47.1,"b":46.9,"c":22.9}
```

I'm trying to highlight the integer with the greatest value. Any advice on how to approach this type of task in Angular?

Comment: your data probably looks like this: $scope.data = {"a":47.1,"b":46.9,"c":22.9} (I think that it's an object, not an array of objects)

Comment: you're right, it's an object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a filter for getting the `maxValue` of your `data`, like this:

```
.filter('getMax', function(){
    return function (data) {
        return Math.max.apply(Math, 
                      Object.keys(data).map(function(key){
                        return data[key]
                      }));

    };
})
```

and then just do this:

```
  <div ng-init="maxItem=(data|getMax)" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <p ng-class="{hightlight:(maxItem===item)}" data-id="home_{{$index}}">{{item}}</p>
  </div>
```

Also, notice that I'm highlighting the maximum one using a class with the `ng-class` directive.

### [Working Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/75kja5zc2OaYLuc5PnST?p=preview)